# why is there python3 and also python3.7 in /usr/local/bin?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, homebrew, zsh, root

I was going around my local folders and found this. they both bring python 3.7.7 shell but why is there a requirement for two files?

#### python was installed using homebrew

[this is what i have in /usr/local/bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYGJE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should be the same binary, on my catalina/macos :

```
.../local/bin$ ls -l python3*
python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
python3.8 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8
```

If I look at ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

```
.../local/bin$ ls -l ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 -> python3.8
```